# Force redirect if a valid taxonomy term is not at the start of the URL?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, redirection, uri

As a follow on from [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4814/remember-users-taxonomy-choice-such-as-which-city-to-filter-the-site-by) I am trying to prepend all URLs on the site with a taxonomy term.

The term itself is handled by a custom module for the most part, however elements of the site such as the calendar modules page view don't allow for me to intervene and theme the link accordingly. If a user goes to the following URL:

- site.com/calendar

Then they should be redirected to:

- site.com/city/calendar

The city itself would be acquired from a cookie set when they hit the front page of the site, or defaults to 'all-cities'.

My vision for such a system was to check in hook_boot against a predefined array for offending patterns (such as **calendar**) and if they are found, then it forces a redirect to the same page but prepends the city.

My gut feeling is that this is a bad approach and possibly un-Drupal. Please let me know if there is a standardized method I should be following for such things.

O’ Salvation, Deliver Me From Evil!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using such system because I also have the gut feeling that this would create some major confusion for modules relying on the drupal path system.

I think you should better deal with subdomains like `city.site.com`.

Comment: If only clients were more flexible :) But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @DanH yeah sure... And what what about Organics Groups ? I'm pretty sure this is the way open atrium has its paths.